# Simple regex with numbers and one letter

Tags: php, regex

I need regex for matching following strings:

```
12D09
1s909
A3434
a1
3F9
t
888
0
```

So, string has maximum 5 chars. They are numbers and one of these may be letter, only one or zero letters {0,1}.

I tried

```
 /[0-9a-z]{1,5}/i
```

but this allows also `aaaa`

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny I know regular expressions not good. In this task I cant't imagine how to do that. /[0-9a-z]{1,5}/i - is not good because it matches 'aaaa', and I need only one letter can be..

Comment: Yes, a lot! Regex dialects differ greatly. For instance, my solution doesn't work for a pure POSIX regex interpreter since POSIX does not define `\d`!

Comment: Sorry, I hurried. I use PHP function preg_replace (PCRE regex syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex would be

```
\b(?!.*[a-z].*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{1,5}\b
```

1. `\b` is a word boundary, those **anchors** are important to avoid partial matches of longer strings, this is the correct choice if you want to match this pattern in a longer string. If those patterns are the complete string, you can also use

   ```
   ^(?!.*[a-z].*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{1,5}$
   ```

   `^` is the anchor for the start of the string and `$` is the end.
2. The negative **lookahead** `(?!.*[a-z].*[a-z])` is matching nothing, its a zero width assertion. It ensures that there are not two letters in the string.
3. The real **pattern** `[a-z0-9]{1,5}` is matching between 1 and 5 letters or digits. this part would allow also more than one letter, but than the negative lookahead would fail and so the complete pattern.
4. [See your pattern](http://regexr.com?2vhga) on the **online testing tool** Regexr

Answer (score 0):

Test your string's length for 5 chars. Substitute `[a-zA-Z]` for nothing. Check that the result after substitution matches *exactly* `^\d{4}`.